# how to parse plaintext from file into a 2d matrix/array?

Tags: c, file

the following code that I wrote is supposed to transform a line taken from a file like the following:

```
(3670, 1882) (1574, 7255) (4814, 8566) (1609, 3153) (9725, 13468) (8297, 3006) (9091, 6989) (8521, 10432) (14669, 12201) (4203, 9729) (469, 2444) (10107, 8318) (1848, 13650) (5423, 847) (11755, 8827) (4451, 4495) (11645, 1670) (10937, 5692) (14533, 13696) (7291, 12158) (1891, 2405) (1776, 4971) (2486, 2499) (13389, 236) (8533, 7531) (10618, 10288) (9119, 11226) (9429, 6622) (12380, 9516) (1698, 5828) (8369, 5101) (11341, 13530) (11955, 2335) (6249, 14435) (9373, 6921) (2977, 2294) (57, 14558) (280, 12847) (13846, 11748) (428, 9004)
```

into a valid 2d matrix.

> {{3670, 1882},{1547, 7255}...}

I'm a good "pythoner" and I'd be able to do that in one line. I wanted to try to solve the same problem in c (note that I started to mess around with c today); my attempt is the following (and the result is quite random/wrong):

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen(argv[1], "rt");

if ( fp != NULL )
{
    char line [1000]; //this is ugly, isn't this?

    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL ) // read a line 
    {
        line[(strlen(line)-1)] = '\0';
        //line[(strlen(line)-2)] = '\0';
        char* p;
        p = strtok(line, ",)( ");

        int elements[100][2]; //even uglier than before?
        int binpos=0;
        int pos=0;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            if (p!=NULL){
                if (binpos==0){
                    elements[pos][binpos]=atoi(p);
                    binpos=1;
                }else{
                    p[(strlen(p)-1)] = '\0'; //remove the comma
                    elements[pos][binpos]=atoi(p);
                    pos++;
                    binpos=0;
                }
            }
            p = strtok(NULL, ",)( ");
        }
        int it;
        for (it=0; it<pos; it++){
            printf("(%d, %d)\n",elements[it][0],elements[it][1]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to correct my mess? :)

Comment: What's your 'mess' doing that you don't think is right?  We're not going to parse all your code out to understand what you're doing.

Comment: nevermind, i just got it, I needed to comment the line removing the coma and it works. Thanks anyways

Comment: Don't use strtok for this.  Read one character at a time, and ouput either that character or the appropriate bracket or comma.  It will clean up the code considerably.

Comment: Thanks william I'll try that. It's for a puzzle so I'm especially trying to reduce memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only be using fgets to read lines if lines are relevant to what you are parsing.  In your case it looks like line endings are irrelevant, so you're better off just using scanf:

```
printf("{");
const char *sep = "";
int a, b;
while (fscanf(fp, "(%d,%d)", &a, &b) == 2) {
    printf("%s{%d, %d}", sep, a, b);
    sep = ", "; }
printf("}");
```

Comment: Great; Well I actually need to put that into a 2d array, not print it.. Excuse my ignorance, but can I make printf print to an array buffer that stuff?